# Copy local file in Saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

I am in a masterless salt-minion, but I would like to manage a file locally. How do I copy a local file around in an Saltstack .sls file?

E.g. something like

```
/etc/mymodule/proxy.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: /mymodule.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to take a look at [`file.copy`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.copy) instead of `file.managed`.

State `file.managed` uses `source` key to download content from URI (can be `salt://`, `http://`, etc.) - it won't intelligently guess that, if there is no URI scheme in `source` value, then it should use local path on the minion it runs at.